# How to get the particular string from URl?

Tags: jquery

Hi all i have an URl which looks like this

```
       http://localhost:60255/Roles/12/Users/
```

i need to get this from the href using jquery from window and i should get this string

```
       http://localhost:60255/Roles/
```

from the url on click event

```
    this is what i had been trying

      var windowpathname = window.location.pathname; window.location.href = windowpathname + "Roles/" + RoleID + "/" + RoleName;
```

in this case when i click that second time

```
       http://localhost:60255/Roles/12/Rahul/Roles/14/Kishore/
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `http://localhost:60255/Roles/`

Comment: i will change the id value on every click

Comment: @MohammadAdil i had edited my question can you check that once

Answer (score 0):

Some properties of object window.location:

```
hash: ""
host: "fiddle.jshell.net"
hostname: "fiddle.jshell.net"
href: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/"
origin: "http://fiddle.jshell.net"
pathname: "/_display/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
window.location.href = window.location.hostname + "/Roles/" + RoleID + "/" + RoleName;
```